# How to parallelize for-loop over an array with Numba

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba, numerical-methods

I'm trying to write a Numba function that loops over a list (not a range) with `@numba.njit(parallel=True)`. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import numba

arr = np.ones(10)
idx = np.array([4, 2, 5])

@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def foo(arr, idx):
    for i in idx:
        arr[i] = 0
    return arr

foo(arr, idx)
```

The warning I get is `NumbaPerformanceWarning: The keyword argument 'parallel=True' was specified but no transformation for parallel execution was possible.` I am aware that one can explicitly parallelize similar loops using `numba.prange()`, but I need the loop to loop over an array of indices. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for i in idx: ...` is semantically an equivalent of:

```py
for j in range(len(idx)):
    i = idx[j]
    [...]
```

The performance of the second version may be slightly different. Based on the second version, you can replace `range` by `prange` and get a parallel version.

However, note that this will cause a race condition if two value of idx are the same. Race conditions results in undefined behaviour (basically, anything can happen).